# DockerHubの`ubuntu:18.04`と`ubuntu:bionic`に違いはありますか？

Tags: docker

単純な興味による質問です。

DockerHubの`ubuntu:18.04`と`ubuntu:bionic`に違いはありますか？
bionicは18.04と同義だという認識です。
Image Historyはどちらも同じでした。

https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/library/ubuntu/18.04/images/sha256-1bbdea4846231d91cce6c7ff3907d26fca444fd6b7e3c282b90c7fe4251f9f86

https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/library/ubuntu/bionic/images/sha256-1bbdea4846231d91cce6c7ff3907d26fca444fd6b7e3c282b90c7fe4251f9f86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

両者は同じものです。

https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/ に、`18.04` と `bionic` が同じ Dockerfile から作られたイメージだと書かれています。

> Supported tags and respective Dockerfile links
>
> - [18.04, bionic-20190912.1, bionic, latest](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/30f325d6526a6dd5ff9f5663a80dcc56db363e2a/bionic/Dockerfile)
> - [18.10, cosmic-20190719, cosmic](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/30f325d6526a6dd5ff9f5663a80dcc56db363e2a/cosmic/Dockerfile)
> - [19.04, disco-20190913, disco, rolling](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/30f325d6526a6dd5ff9f5663a80dcc56db363e2a/disco/Dockerfile)
> - [19.10, eoan-20190916, eoan, devel](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/30f325d6526a6dd5ff9f5663a80dcc56db363e2a/eoan/Dockerfile)
> - [16.04, xenial-20190904, xenial](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/30f325d6526a6dd5ff9f5663a80dcc56db363e2a/xenial/Dockerfile)

(2019年10月1日時点での記述を引用)